# What size sub-panel and wire do I need for my three-season room?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, subpanel

I have a 15x22 room that is roughly 50' from the main panel, that I am converting from a 3 season room, into a conditioned space (heating and cooling, enclosed with windows and doors, etc.).

Currently there is a single 110 outlet in this room. This will not be sufficient as I want this to be a fully functional room that I can use most of the year. That said, I want to put in one of those split wall heating/ac units, maybe a ceiling fan, lights and enough outlets to fill the room while still meeting code.

I live in upstate New York. I plan to put a back-up fridge (which I know is supposed to be on its own circuit for starting amps), maybe a plug in lamp, tv, and a few other small items that won't necessarily all be on at the same time.

I looked at Home Depot and found a 6awg 3 wire cable with ground that says the max amperes are 55. So my question is, basically, on the proper amperes for this room, a proper sized sub panel and the correct breakers, so that I don't overload the sub panel and catch the wire on fire from overheating.

As I looked around HD's website, I began feeling like I would need a 100 amp sub panel at a minimum as the available slots for what I need don't seem to come on a panel that is rated for the 6awg wire specs. Do I need a larger (4awg) wire and a minimum of a 4 slot panel? I figured I could put lights one 1 slot, outlets one 1 and a double pole breaker for the heating/ac unit on one. Any help mapping this out would be pretty great.

Thanks, Bob

p.s: The main panel is pretty full, but I had installed an electric tankless water heater that took 6 spots for 3 double pole breakers for each heating element that I can steal the space from since the wife doesn't like that the 27,000kW makes the lights in the house flicker, so we went back to a standard tank water heater.

[image: service panel]

Panel is a Square-D Homeline HOMC30UC Series S01.

Comment: I would be surprised if 50 amps won't do a room of that size, your largest load will be the heat/ ac. You don't add the size of the breakers but the loads to develop what size you need. In any case you can use a 100 amp panel with more available spaces and feed it with a 50 amp breaker. If your area gets really cold or hot in NY you might need a larger service but I heat the same square footage uninsulated steel buildings with 5kw heaters and this still leaves plenty of power for outlets and lighting.

Comment: I can't believe you actually got correct information at Home Depot!!  Yes #6 is rated 55A but you can round upward to the next size breaker, or 60A.

Comment: Can you post photos of your main panel?

Comment: I read info that was posted on the home depot website. I imagine they just regurgitate whatever info comes with the items. That said, I will include a pic of my main service. It is a 200 amp service. This is on a 4 bedroom farmhouse with attached garage. I thought you wanted to have your breaker slight lower than the wire rating so you dont overheat it?! Am I thinking backwards on that?

Comment: Breaker <= wire rating. But you can put (within certain limits) a < 100A breaker into a 100A panel - Harper or one of the others will explain how to "go big".

Comment: Can you post a picture of the directory label for your main panel please, and how many square feet your house is for that matter?

Comment: sorry to whomever is moderating my posts. I do not know how to add a photo to a comment, only as an answer.

Comment: We're looking for a chart that says something like "1/2 = Air Conditioner, 3 = Kitchen Receptacles, 4 = Upstairs Lighting, etc."

Comment: ok, I will look for that. I don't recall seeing something like that. Also, the sqft'age is 1450 according to the sale info.

Comment: ohhh. Well that's embarrassing. The directory has literally nothing more than what I have put on it over time when I work on a room. Typically I plug in a dirty signal finder and shut off the circuit, then I go up and use a voltage meter to make sure I got the correct one. This usually requires me to check all electric circuits in any given room because, being an old farmhouse, the electrician that updated the service connected several wires in whatever way they seemed fit to make it work. sometimes a breaker will get flipped and lights or outlets in the several parts of the house go off.

Comment: also, based on my picture, I can tell you a few things. Top right is the hot water heating boiler, the 40 am half way down on the left is the hot water heater tank for domestic water, the 50 amp below that goes to a double oven-electric stove, the 50 amp below that one feed a sub panel that feeds power to my pool pump and barn, below that is a 40amp and the one adjacent to that (also 40 amp) fed the on demand hot water heater (out of service), there is a 30 amp above that that I can't honestly tell you what it goes to. Above that is a double pole 20 amp that the electrician used for 2 circuits

Comment: everything else is outlets and lights. I dont have any real big ticket items. No central air, no major 3phase toys or anything like that.

Comment: How many branch circuits do you have feeding the receptacles in your kitchen?

Comment: Also, is your dryer electric or gas?

Comment: ahhh, that has to be the circuit I didn't know about. It is electric

Comment: @Bobb32x that's one down :) as to the kitchen receptacles?

Comment: none are above 20 amps. I would want the microwave one its own and the fridge but as I mentioned before, the guy that updated the wiring kind of piggybacked a bunch of wires to make it work. The kitchen is above a crawl space that I don't have access to without pulling up tile and opening a trap door. That said, when I moved in, I moved the fridge to another side and ran its own wire, so at least I have that. 12 outlets in total. 12x30 kitchen

Comment: How many watts is your hot water tank, come to think of it?  Also, do you know what size your barn is, and the HP rating of your pool pump? Furthermore, are there pool heaters or other accessories we should worry about there?

Comment: 1 1/2 hp pool pump. No heaters or accessories. the barn is very low wattage. I mean,4 lights and like 2 outlets. I can trip it with a pancake compressor if I am not careful. hot water tank is 4500/3380 upper, lower and total. I think that is because it only runs one at a time and as the water stratifies, it goes to the upper one?!

Comment: Can you figure out which breakers turn off the receptacles for the kitchen+dining room?

Comment: I have the dirty signal finder so yeah for sure. Side bar.. I spoke with an electrician at my work and he said I need 2-2-2-4 wire. If this is the case, to make certain I am following code, can I run the wire perpendicular to the studs and strap them to the underside face of each stud or is it code to drill holes and run them up and out of the way?

Comment: @Bobb32x -- we'll get to wire sizing once we finish working out all the loads :)

Comment: @Bobb32x -- were you able to figure out which breakers control the kitchen counter  receptacles?

Comment: sorry ThreePhaseEel, holidays had me super busy. Yes, I can shut off half of the receptacles with 1 breaker, and 3 others are on another circuit attached to a nearby room that has 2 receptacles, and then on to another room for 2 receptacles. 20a

Answer (score 2):

### You don't *need* that big of a feeder, but if you're going to put in a subpanel, you might as well take the chance to free up space in your main panel

Doing an Article 220 calculation for your feeder alone, with 990VA for the lighting, a 1500VA extra allowance for receptacle loads, and 2875VA for a 10A@230V mini-split (12kBTU/20SEER) at 125% (as the largest motor on the feeder), gives us a 22A feeder, far short of even the 60A that 6/3 NM is limited to.  However, I would run either a 1/0-1/0-1/0-2 Al SER cable (good for a 125A feeder) or a 1.5" EMT (with stud shoes, but also good for 125A tops with 1/0 Al XHHW-2s in it) between the main panel and the subpanel.

This allows us to put in a 125A, 24 or 30 space, main lug panel for the subpanel (a HOM2448L125PGC provides a nice, easy package solution if you wish to stick with Homeline), with a HOM2125 for the feeder breaker. Even with two 15A AFCIs (HOM115CAFI in Homeline) for receptacles, and a 15A double pole breaker (HOM215) for the air conditioner, this still leaves ample room for future expansion, which is a *good thing* considering that your main panel is basically full: you can get 2 spare spots by pulling out the other 40A breaker from the tankless experiment, but that's it, and you'll need those spaces to retrofit AFCI protection as there are no double-stuff AFCIs.

The HOM2125 replaces one of the unused 40A breakers that originally went to the tankless heater, by the way.  Also note that you will need to torque all lugs to specification with an inch-pound torque wrench or torque screwdriver; this requirement was enshrined in Code in 2017 with 110.14(D), in addition to being a good idea lest [your electrical system pull a Greg Biffle on you](https://iaeimagazine.org/magazine/2010/07/16/the-difference-between-success-and-failure-how-a-torque-wrench-improves-system-reliability/).